# After upgrade to Ice Cream Sandwich my Samsung Galaxy S2 camera cannot focus

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, camera, focus

After upgrading to new Android version (Ice Cream Sandwich) my camera cannot focus. All the pictures made by my phone are blurry (not focused). I tried to reset camera settings to default, I tried clearing apps data (of my camera), I installed another camera application - nothing helped.

Interesting is, that the camera can focus on objects, that are relatively close (50 cm) but object that are further are blurry.

My front-camera works fine (the one on the display side)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: There could be other core apps or services involved besides Camera that could be causing this.  I would recommend a factory reset.

Comment: Unfortunately the factory reset did not help. It is still the same.

Comment: Was this an official over-the-air (OTA) update from your carrier, or is it a custom ROM?

Comment: Regular (official) update through Kies. No custom ROM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it is HW issue. Unfortunately it occurred at the same time as I upgraded to ICS, but it is a HW issue.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a long shot but check the camera lens, it might have a small piece of see through plastic that starts to get worn out.

Pictures on my new phone were blurry right from the start and I didn't know what to do. Then I noticed that the lens felt a bit rubbery, so I scratched very carefully with my nails and to my amazement the small piece of rubber was removed. Now I have 100% clear pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but fixed it by resetting my camera settings. First switch off your phone and switch it back on, then reset your camera settings.

Comment: This is kind of vague. How exactly did you reset your camera settings?